# How to use statistics for analyzing empirical data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I came up with the certain identity relating difference between Pi and convergents to Pi on the left hand side via expression with five integer parameters (n i j k l) on the right hand side.

For each "n" I obtained some empirical solutions in the form of (i j k l) set via computer program utilizing brute force trial and error.

It appears that there an infinite number of solutions exists for each value of "n" and, therefore the number of parameters dependent on "n" could be reduced from 4 down to 2 (or even 1?).

The small portion of computed empirical solutions is shown below where what shown in the parentheses are (i j k l).

Is there statistical method to find how each of (i j k l) separately depend on "n" (or at least how i,j,k,l relate to each other)?

How many "n" and how much data within each "n" should be covered to make it sufficient for statistical analysis?

PS Looking at the below data it is seen that for all cases

Abs(l - j) = 2*m where "m" is some integer value.

n = 2 ==> ( -1 -1 1 1)

n = 2 ==> ( 5 1 79 1 )

n = 2 ==> ( -105 3 15703 1)

n = 2 ==> ( 3003 5 3265501 1)

n = 2 ==> ( -17017 7 117197427 1)

n = 2 ==> ( 323323 9 12938569465 1)

n = 2 ==> ( -26558675 11 5822357747957 1 )

n = 2 ==> ( 145568097675 13 167497581760018981 1 )

n = 2 ==> ( -14325749295 15 83748791323596173 1)

...

n = 2 ==> ( 37825425 16 11338429672808230471587052268612747 36)

...

n = 3 ==> (-21 0 1 0)

n = 3 ==> (-5 1 1 1)

n = 3 ==> ( 105 3 137 1 )

n = 3 ==> ( -3003 5 29219 1 )

n = 3 ==> ( 17017 7 1046413 1)

...

n = 3 ==> ( -113476275 16 32102060152077381820091 12)

n = 3 ==> ( 429 -1 283 13)

n = 3 ==> ( 16445 11 13836450782495167 13 )

n = 4 ==> (318 0 -13 0)

n = 4 ==> (265 1 197 5)

n = 5 ==> (-339 0 14 0)

n = 5 ==> (791 2 25 8)

n = 6 ==> (47201 4 124360 14)

n = 7 ==> (-2409 4 1349 12)

n = 8 ==> ( -66317 -1 9977 1)

n = 8 ==> ( -6963285 3 212651 1)

n = 8 ==> ( -66383317 7 833127 1)

n = 8 ==> ( -103605391175 11 720252257 1)

n = 8 ==> ( -55884747999795 15 517817918873 1)

n = 8 ==> ( -66317 0 8805 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -2188461 4 89050 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -16380299 8 317214 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -1305427928805 12 23297755114 2)

n = 8 ==> ( 896546759355 14 27371124886 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -23756674250925 16 5393931750178 2)

n = 8 ==> ( -66317 1 8246 3)

Comment: Welcome to CV, Alex. "... how parameters in each possible four parameters subset correlate with each other across all 16 sets" makes little sense and is ambiguous.  Could you clarify what you are looking for, perhaps by describing your objective in English?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any "dataset with four integer parameters ... {n, i, j, k, l}." They all have five.  And what would a "correlation ... between [a] parameter and ... subsets" be?  How would you measure it?

Comment: @whuber Sorry I didn't make it clear - all datasets are indeed with 5 integer parameters {n, i, j, k, l} - however "n" represents an "argument" while { i, j, k, l} are presumably functionally dependent on "n" but also those four are presumably expressible via each other - note that it is already observed that in all 16 sets Abs(l-j)=2*m where "m" is yet another integer.

Comment: @whuber I edited my question to make it absolutely clear and containing sufficient level of details. Please reopen my question - I am really in need of getting answers!

Comment: Greetings Alex! FYI the giant list of $n$ values you added to your question aren't helpful, as they flood the question with a lot of unnecessary information. Perhaps you can narrow it down to a small set of cases or make it clear in some other way without so many redundant values.

Comment: @Shawn Hemelstrand - Thanks! I narrowed the list down per your request.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to find or how is it related to statistics. Can you define precisely what your goal is ? The statement "...therefore the number of parameters dependent on "n" could be reduced from 4 down to 2" is also unclear.  What parameters are you referring to? how does this follow from the fact that there are infinitely many solutions ?

Comment: @J. Delaney See "Is there statistical method to find how each of (i j k l) separately depend on "n" (or at least how i,j,k,l relate to each other)?" The statement "...therefore the number of parameters dependent on "n" could be reduced from 4 down to 2" refers to i,j,k,l. I am assuming that presence of infinite number   of i,j,k,l solutions for any "n" constitutes the fact that tne number of above mentioned parameters could be reduced (am I wrong?). This reduction should be achieved by finding dependencies within i, j, k, l solution set. BTW, all found solutions have abs(l-j) = 2*m relation.

Comment: @Alex I have no idea on what basis you are assuming that the number of parameters can be reduced. You did not provide any background information to justify it, so it's impossible for me to tell if you are wrong or not.  In any case, finding precise relations between the parameters is not a statistical problem, hence there are no statistical methods that can help you.

Comment: @J. Delaney Could perhaps statistical methods give some hints how parameters relate to each other?

Comment: @Alex If I understand correctly you are looking for *deterministic* relations between the parameters. I don't see how statistical methods can help with that.  It seems to me that a much more fruitful approach would be to use your knowledge of what those parameters actually represent,  in order to understand if such relations exist.

Comment: @J.Delaney, couldn't this be understood as there is a huge population of deterministic solutions, but all that Alex has is a sample?

Comment: @Alex, I think it is perfectly ok to try to use statistical methods to reveal patterns in data :) (+1). However, if you analyse your quadruplets as a statistical sample, this comes with the tacit assumption that every posdible quadrupley was picked with the same probability. Does your brute force algorithm guarantee for that? Otherwise you may see artificial patterns due to the algorithm

Comment: On top of the difficulty with seeing patterns from your algorithm instead of your population, it would be difficult to detect relations  such as j mod i = k*l mod j and the like.

Comment: @Ute The OP is trying to find exact relations between the parameters. For example, just making something up, it could be that i = n^gcd(j,k) mod l+1.  Finding such relations is not a matter of statistics. ( It is also not particularly well defined, since one can always find infinitely many such relations that exactly hold for any given *finite* dataset)

Comment: @J.Delaney is right in that you cannot prove anything by statistics. If you find a relationship in the sample you generated by brute force, and you trust on your algorithm picking solutions with equal likelihood, you still do not know if there are others that do not follow the newly found pattern. For example, if m<37 in the data, you don't have any argument to prove or disprove that this holds for your population

Comment: @J.Delaney I am not expecting to find exact deterministic solutions from the application of statistical methods, neither I am looking for any kind pf proofs - I am just looking for any possible revelation of any probabilistic trends in relation between the parameters. The brute force computation used to obtain data provides that  generated samples have the same probabilities. I understand that there are might be patterns which are not covered in the collection of samples which I have - I am just looking for what could be derived from the samples I already have.

Comment: @Ute I am not expecting to find exact deterministic solutions from the application of statistical methods, neither I am looking for any kind pf proofs - I am just looking for any possible revelation of any probabilistic trends in relation between the parameters. The brute force computation used to obtain data provides that  generated samples have the same probabilities. I understand that there are might be patterns which are not covered in the collection of samples which I have - I am just looking for what could be derived from the samples I already have.

Comment: @Alex Can you give as an example of how one such a "probabilistic trend in relation between the parameters" might look like ?

Comment: @J. Delaney For example, let say, some sort of  indication that for any "n" parameters "i" and "k" are more related to each other comparing with the relation of either one of two above with "j" or with "l".

Comment: @Alex what does "more related to each other" mean ? you will need to formulate your hypothesis more precisely in order for this to be meaningful

Comment: @J. Delaney I don't have more precise details. My hypothesis is strictly empirically based. That is why I am seeking what help I could get from statistical methods to get some hints how to proceed further.

Comment: @Alex, it is difficult to say anything for data coming from a black box (your algorithm). My impression from your examples is: the algorithm chooses n, then l, then j, then somehow finds i and k or no solution. The fact that the data leave this impression could be used as a hint, if we knew how the algorithm really works.

Comment: @Ute Yes - your description of programing algorithm is correct.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, this is important to know (for a statistician)! How does the algorithm decide to choose n, l, j : start with n=2, then try all l=1, j = -1,... to j_max1_, l=2 (3?), .. ? how do you determine j_max_l, , l_max?

Comment: Another question: is it (theoretically) possible that a combination of (n, j, l) yields more than one (i,k)? Or is it only zero or one? If more solutions (i, k) are possible, do you then find the smallest in some way? (smallest i, smallest k)?

Comment: @Ute On the first question - there is no known to me theoretical upper limit on any of the parameters (variables) - those in the program are chosen arbitrary - to limit (otherwise infinite) program output. On the second question - it is not known to me whether there are multiple {i, k} solutions for any (all or some or one or none) {n, j, l} combination. Because among found "i" were huge negative values I think "i" does not have low bound.

Comment: OK, does you algorithm stop searching for a given (n,j,l) when it has found (i,k)? and can it determine if there is no (i,k) for a given (n,j,l)?

Comment: @Ute On the first quest - it doesn't stop, on the second - no it can't.

Comment: Do you know how many unsuccessful attempts the algorithm has made to find solutions for a given (n,j,l)

Comment: @Ute The used program did not keep the count of the failed attempts - I guess it could have had the feature to print the number of the failed attempts between finding each "current" solution and the "previous" one... but at the time of writing the program the need for such feature was not anticipated.

Comment: are you familiar with / have you heard about *probabilistic number theory*? (I myself have only heard about it)

Comment: @Alex maybe you can share the remaining data as an excel sheet / google sheet / csv file via google drive or similar

Comment: @Ute How much "n"-wise, "i"-wise, "j"-wise, "k"-wise and "l"-wise data would be sufficient for suitable for this problem statistical/probabilistic analysis?

Comment: @Alex, "statistical analysis" is too big a word, as stated in SextusEmpiricus answer one would need more background information. What you can do is just trying to describe what the data look like, but interpretation would be questionable, since your algorithm is a black box (at least as you present it). You could provide the data that you wisely removed to make your question readable (the dots).

Comment: @Ute I opened the chatroom called "How to use statistics for analyzing empirical data?" Could you join me there - I could share the data with you there.

Comment: @Ute Now I can't find that room... May be you could find it...?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there statistical method to find how each of (i j k l) separately depend on "n

Statistical analysis is not very fruitful when there is no idea about the meaning of the data. All the information that you provide is just that you have a list of quintuple integers.

Without any further information it can not be said whether such statistical method exist. It depends in the first place on whether the data has a dependency.

You need to start with some hypothesis based on knowledge that is exterior to the data. The data can help you to cover the gaps in the knowledge, but the data can not create all of it.

Data contains information, but it is useless without any prior information about how it should be interpreted. The statistical method is an additative process. It describes the ways how we can *add* the information from data to pre-existing knowledge. Without knowing what pre-existing knowledge the information from your data is supposed to relate to, it is not possible to suggest statistical methods.

Comment: If I will make an assumption that for any "n" parameters "i" and "k" are more related to each other comparing with the relation of either one of two above with "j" or with "l" and that parameters "j" and "l" are more related to each other comparing with the relation of either one of two above with "i" or with "k" - will this help in applying statistical methods of data analysis and if "yes" then how? What methods then could be used?  Could above assumptions be somewhat confirmed or rejected by the methods of statistical analysis?

Comment: @Alex a term like 'related' is very broad and you can not test any relationship. But if you have an idea about the properties of the relationship then you can test it. A similar situation is a [test for randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test). How can you test whether a range of 0's and 1's is random, like 0000000000 or 1001011100 is any of these more or less random? This can only be tested when you restrict yourself to *specific* ways that lack of randomness might occur. Without a context you can not test dependence.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about finding structures in a five dimensional, integer valued dataset. The five variables, $n, i,j,k,l$, have a complex dependence structure in that they appear in a number theoretic equation which is not given here, but can be found in [another question by OP on math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860499/seeking-proof-for-the-formula-relating-pi-with-its-convergents). The data result from some non disclosed brute force algorithm - a black box.

The question does not provide a statistical hypothesis, but rather asks for ideas for *exploratory* analysis that could help to find relations between the variables.

Looking at the provided data examples, it seems that

- the brute force mechanism used to find the data first chooses $n$, then $l$, then $j$, then somehow finds $i$ and $k$ or no solution. This has been confirmed by OP in the comments.
- the absolute values of $i$ and $k$ tend to increase

  - as $n$ increases,
  - as $j$ increases.

One possibility to quantify the "eye-balling results" and analyse these data is to treat $n, j$ and $l$ as independent variables and try to fit a model for $i$ and $k$ as dependent variables. The increase seems exponential, so maybe one would rather want to look at the logarithm of $i$ and $k$. This would however ignore the complicated and perhaps subtle true connections between the variables, and could give misleading results. Also, one has to be aware that a fitted linear or nonlinear model would just be an exploratory vehicle, and p-values and the like are invalid.

It does sometimes make sense to consider number theoretical functions as quasi-random, although they are fundamentally deterministic. Already in the 1930s, Paul Erdős, Mark Kac and Aurel Wintner  started taking this point of view and thus founded *probabilistic number theory*. Emmanuel Kowalski has written comprehensive [lecture notes on probabilistic number theory](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ekowalski/probabilistic-number-theory.pdf).